# objective-c 'double free' error in ARC mode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to practice the block and GCD/NSOperation, so I wrote this project [Async-objc](https://github.com/disorderdev/Async-objc), but when I'm trying to test it with unit test, I always encountered 'double free' error, I thought there shouldn't be such error in ARC mode.

here is the code

```
- (void)each:(NSArray *)items iterator:(callbackEach)iterator complete:(callbackWithError)complete {
    NSBlockOperation *blockOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (!items || items.count == 0) {
            complete(nil);
            return;
        }

        callbackWithError __block completeOnce = complete;
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"start operations %@", queue);
        [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:kMaxConcurrentOperationCount];
        NSInteger __block count = 0;
        for (id item in items) {
            NSOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                iterator(item, ^(NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        completeOnce(error);
                        completeOnce = nil;
                    } else {
                        count++;
                        if (count >= items.count) {
                            completeOnce(nil);
                            completeOnce = nil;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }];

            [queue addOperation:op];
        }

        [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
        NSLog(@"all operations are down %@", queue);
    }];
    [_mainQueue addOperation:blockOp];
}
```

this is the test code:

```
- (void)testEachWithBigData {
    BOOL __block completed = false;
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; ++i) {
        [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
    [_async each:items
        iterator:^(id item, callbackWithError callback) {
            //NSLog(@"======item %@", item);
            NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[item integerValue]];
            //NSLog(@"number %@", num);
            [result addObject:num];

            callback(nil);
        }
        complete:^(NSError *error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                STAssertNil(error, @"there should be no error");
                [result sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                    NSNumber *num1 = (NSNumber *)obj1;
                    NSNumber *num2 = (NSNumber *)obj2;
                    if ([num1 integerValue] > [num2 integerValue]) {
                        return NSOrderedDescending;
                    } else if ([num1 integerValue] < [num2 integerValue]) {
                        return NSOrderedAscending;
                    }
                    return NSOrderedSame;
                }];

                NSInteger index = 1;
                for (NSNumber *num in result) {
                    STAssertEquals(index, [num integerValue], @"the value should be ordered");
                    index++;
                }
                completed = YES;
            });
        }
     ];

    NSDate *until = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    while (!completed && [until timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:until];
    }
}
```

If you couldn't reproduce the error, increase the test item count to 10000.

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; ++i) {
        [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    }
```

and **comment the NSLog()**
then Command + U to run the unit test

here is the error message:
otest(11105,0xb039f000) malloc: *** error for object 0xa0f8000: pointer being freed was not allocated

otest(11209,0xb0115000) malloc: *** error for object 0x41dcc00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I cannot reproduce the 'double free' error this time

Comment: I can't repro anything, even with 100,000 items.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "double free" error. I don't get an error, either.

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: run the unit test multiple times, then I can get the error